# RadioButton not showing as "Checked" when bound value is true

Tags: xaml, mvvm

In my project I am setting a bool property as true when constructing my ViewModel.

In the View, I have a RadioButton which is bound to the value of this property.  The first time I open the View, the RadioButton is "checked" (perfect, exactly what I want!).

However, if I close and then re-open the View, the RadioButton is not "checked", despite the bound property having a value of 'true'.  In my constructor I am setting 'StaggeredMode' to true, but the setter is being called three times (firstly, value = true; secondly, value = false; thirdly, value = true)

Any help will be appreciated!

XAML:

```
<RadioButton GroupName="AppointmentStart" 
             Content="Staggered"
             IsChecked="{Binding StaggeredMode, Mode=TwoWay}"
             VerticalAlignment="Top" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             Margin="310,247,0,0" />
```

C#:

```
private bool staggeredMode;
public bool StaggeredMode
{
    get { return staggeredMode; }
    set { staggeredMode = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `StaggeredMode` property should be observable so the view can be notified about property changes from your `ViewModel`.

You can implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) by yourself or use one of existing implementations like [this](http://www.mvvmlight.net/help/SL5/html/d457231f-6af7-601d-fa1f-1fe7c9f60c57.htm), [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg431509(v=pandp.50).aspx) or [this](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/observableobject).

Here is a basic implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface:

```
public abstract class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you derive your ViewModel from ObservableObject and raise OnPropertyChanged event every time your property value has been changed:

```
public class MyViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    ...
    private bool staggeredMode;
    public bool StaggeredMode
    {
        get { return staggeredMode; }
        set
        {
            staggeredMode = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("StaggeredMode");
        }
    }
    ...
}
```